# why the latest values are overriding into array of object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, overriding

```
<html>
    <head>


        <style type="text/css">
            #mycanvas{
                width:500px;
                height:450px;
                border:2px solid green;

                font-size:30px;
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            window.onload = function (){
                vcan = {};
                vcan.main = {}
                vcan.main.repNode = [];
                vcan.main.currentTransform = {'id':0, 'name':'myobj'}

                document.getElementById("mycanvas").addEventListener('mousemove', mymousemove);

                function mymousemove(){
                    var  currAdTime = new Date().getTime();
                    console.log(currAdTime);
                    var myObj = extend(vcan.main.currentTransform , {mdTime:currAdTime, func:'add'})
                    vcan.main.repNode.push(myObj);
                }

              function    extend (fobj, sobj){
                    if((typeof fobj == 'object') && (typeof sobj == 'object')){
                    for(var prop in sobj){
                        fobj[prop] = sobj[prop];
                    }
                        return fobj;
                    }else{
                        alert("it seems that the arguments you passed are not object");
                    }
                }   

                document.getElementById("test").onclick = function (){

                    var output = "";
                    for(var i=0; i< vcan.main.repNode.length; i++){
                        output +=   vcan.main.repNode[i].mdTime;    
                        output += "<br />";

                    }

                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;

                }

            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="mycanvas">
            Please move the mouse inside this box
            And click on Show Result
        </div>

        <button id="test">
            Show Result
        </button>

        <div id="result">

        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

For solve problem please render these above code into browser. After click on Show Result button there would be shown time. My question is that why all the same time are displaying.

The latest value of time is overriding into different element of array of object.

At the same time if we see the console then time would be different.

After long search, I could not solve this problem. Please guys help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Fiddled: [http://jsfiddle.net/WacV4/](http://jsfiddle.net/WacV4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fixed solution http://jsfiddle.net/WacV4/1/. Object in JS are assigned by reference not by copying its values, so `myObj` in `mymousemove` always modifies the same value. You just need to copy `vcan.main.currentTransform` before extending.

Comment: Thanks for solved this problem. I appreciate it, But one question I have that Is not it going to affect performance wise if the program has lot of objects. Because copy to properties of all object is expensive program. What you say?

Comment: As I see objects in this example have just a couple of keys, so in this case performance is not you should think about.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your extend function with this one

```
function extend(fobj, sobj) {
  if ((typeof fobj == 'object') && (typeof sobj == 'object')) {
    var newfobj = Object();
    for (var prop in fobj) {
      newfobj[prop] = fobj[prop];
    }
    for (var prop in sobj) {
      newfobj[prop] = sobj[prop];
    }
    return newfobj;
  } else {
    alert("it seems that the arguments you passed are not object");
  }
}
```

Comment: `{}` could be used instead of `Object()`

Comment: Thanks Amir, have you seen what I did comment on bjornd post. Please read it.

Comment: It depends on your program purpose. Exactly in this code and without thinking about writting whole program, If I were you, I whould make a new object instead of calling extend. BUT if you mention your program goal, we can help more in Performance.

Comment: Okay..I have a array which has lot of objects, as the same time the particular object has average properties. so If I follow of you guy's method then all properties of all object of an array would be copy, in this case I think the performance would matter. I hope bjornd is listening here. What you suggest guys please tell it.

Comment: I have read your code and i think you could use something like a dictionary, while part of your data doesn't change and i conjecture you have lots of them. Do you know how? var Dic= { Key: YOURKEY, Value: []}

Answer (score 0):

Somthing goes wrong in the extend function. Im not sure what the suggested out put should be but the returned object from this function always has the same time. perhaps you should return sobj instead?? it seams the loop is not doing what you want perhaps. I added a `console.log(myObj);` after its creation and this shows that the same time goes in to myObj everytime. If you want more help I suggest you add what your wished output could look like in the text.

Regards Pablo.