# loop over array and add separate objects to new array - only one item in new array

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am making a call to a backend API which returns a JSON response. I have read a number of answers on here including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706360/why-the-latest-values-are-overriding-into-array-of-object-in-javascript) but they dont seem to cover my issue.

The **JSON** response from the API looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1", 
        "name": "test1",
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "test2",
    }
]
```

My **Angular JS** code looks like this:

```
controller.testDetailHolder = [];

Test.getAllTests.query({}, function(data){
            for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
                controller.testDetailHolder.name = data[i].name;
                controller.testDetailHolder.id = data[i].id;
            }   
        });
```

When I `console.log` controller.testDetailHolder it only shows the second value from the GET request (i.e. the array just holds one value) however, I want the controller.testDetailHolder to look like this:

```
controller.testDetailHolder = [
    {
        id: "1", 
        name: "test1",
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "test2",
    }
]
```

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
controller.testDetailHolder = [];

Test.getAllTests.query({}, function(data){
            for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
                controller.testDetailHolder.push({
                    name : data[i].hours,
                    id   : data[i].id
                });
            }   
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is constantly overwriting `controller.testDetailHolder`, so you need to use array syntax:

```
Test.getAllTests.query({}, function(data){
            for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
                controller.testDetailHolder[i].name = data[i].hours;
                                           ^^^ 
                controller.testDetailHolder[i].id = data[i].id;
            }   
        });
```

Comment: hey simon, thanks for your help on this... everyone has given the same answer but as you were the first I wanted to ask --- it is saying `Cannot set property 'hours' of undefined` --- any idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: In your situation I would use devtools to indirect the data object being returned

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the data like:

```
Test.getAllTests.query({}, function(data){
  controller.testDetailHolder = data;
});
```

Or use push to add it to the existing array:

```
Test.getAllTests.query({}, function(data){
  Array.prototype.push.apply(controller.testDetailHolder, data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`controller.testDetailHolder` is the array itself, not an element within the array. You want to add the values as elements, which is accessed by `controller.testDetailHolder[i]`, where `i` is the index of the element. Modify your code to be:

```js
controller.testDetailHolder[i].name = data[i].hours;
controller.testDetailHolder[i].id = data[i].id;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are completely overwriting the complete `testDetailHolder` array, because you do not specify an index when setting the values.

`controller.testDetailHolder.name` should be `controller.testDetailHolder[i].name`

---

Another issue is that you are using `data[i].hours` when `hours` is not defined on the JSON.

---

Lastly since you want to copy the whole object you could just do a single assignment

```
Test.getAllTests.query({}, function(data){
        controller.testDetailHolder = data;  
    });
```